# The right way to create pointer to pointer object?

Tags: c++

What is the right way to create a pointer to pointer object? Like for example,

```
int **foo;
foo = new int[4][4];
```

Then the compiler gives me an error saying "cannot convert from int (*)[4] to int **.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use some 2D array class for this. Especially so since you don't know how to make it manually. (If you knew, you should at least _write_ a 2D array class.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int **foo = new int*[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   foo[i] = new int[4];
```

**Clarification:**

In many languages the code above is called a jagged array and it's only useful when the "rows" have different sizes. C++ has no direct language support for dynamically allocated rectangular arrays, but it's easy to write it yourself:

```
int *foo = new int[width * height];
foo[y * height + x] = value;
```

Comment: Try it now. I've removed the parentheses from the first "new" statement around the type. This compiles with GCC 4.3, at least.

Comment: *"C++ has no direct language support for rectangular arrays"* is simply wrong. Writing `int foo[4][4]` gives you a rectangular array. Dynamic multi-dimensional arrays are tricky, to be sure, and are addressed in multiple questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I should have written dynamic rectangular arrays, you are right.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.16 ... for anyone interested in multi-dimensional arrays in C++.

Comment: I think you mean “*jagged* array”, not “jugged.”

Answer (score 8):

Using raw `new` is a bit unwieldy to use. The inner dimension (last 4) must be a compile time constant, in addition. You also have to remember to delete the array once you are finished using it.

```
int (*foo)[4] = new int[4][4];
foo[2][3] = ...;
delete[] foo;
```

If that feels too "syntactic braindead", you can use typedef to prettify it

```
typedef int inner_array[4];
inner_array *foo = new int[4][4];
foo[2][3] = ...;
delete[] foo;
```

That's called a **rectangular** 2-dimensional array, because all the rows (4 of them, which can be determined at runtime) have the same width (which must be known at compile time).

Alternatively, use `std::vector`, with which you don't need to mess around with delete anymore, and which will also handle the raw pointer mess:

```
std::vector<int> v(4 * 4);
v[index] = ...;
```

You may later add or remove integers from the vector as you wish. You could also create a `vector< vector<int> >`, but i find it unwieldy to use, because you have to manage the separate row-vectors (which can be of varying lengths), and they are not seen as "one unit" together.

You can always create a function that maps a two dimensional coordinate to a one-dimensional index

```
inline int two_dim(int x, int y) {
  return y * 4 + x;
}

v[two_dim(2, 3)] = ...;
```

For a simple two-dimensional array whose size you know beforehand, you don't need `new` at all, though

```
int x[4][4]; 
x[2][3] = ...;
```